# Why is my variable not incrementing?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a very basic slider. I managed to create something but I am stuck when I try to change from one slide to another. I was thinking my code would work but it does not and I don't understand why.

[Here's a link to a codepen of it](https://codepen.io/oehaut/pen/brZXav)

Here's the relevant part of my problem:

I have defined a slider like so:

```
var carrousel = document.getElementById('carrouselcontainer');

var slide1 = document.createElement('div');
slide1.className = 'slide1';

var slide2 = document.createElement('div');
slide2.className = 'slide2';

var slide3 = document.createElement('div');
slide3.className = 'slide3';

var slider = [slide1, slide2, slide3]

carrousel.appendChild(slider[0]);
```

And this does work. Now I am trying to add a function that will increment or decrement the slider variable when clicked.

```
var backButton = document.getElementById('backButton');
var forwardButton = document.getElementById('forwardButton')

function forward() {
  slider++
}

forwardButton.addEventListener('click', forward)
```

But when I click on the `forwardButton` element, nothing happens. I know that the `eventListener` is working since I tried a `window.alert()` message on it and it works when I click it. What is it that I am doing wrong here?

Comment: `slider` is an array. What do you expect to happen when you increment (`++`) it?

Comment: Slider is an array, so you'd want to increase the index value, not the array itself.

Comment: Thanks both of you. Apparently my understanding of how to manipulate an array is erroneous. The example given here are helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some kind of index which you use to get something out of your array:

```js
var forwardButton = document.getElementById('forwardButton');
var result = document.getElementById('carrouselcontainer');
var sliderIndex = 0;


var slider1 = document.createElement("div");
slider1.innerHTML = "item 1";
var slider2 = document.createElement("div");
slider2.innerHTML = "item 2";
var slider3 = document.createElement("div");
slider3.innerHTML = "item 3";

var slider = [slider1, slider2, slider3];
result.appendChild(slider[sliderIndex]);

function forward() {
  result.removeChild(slider[sliderIndex]);
  sliderIndex = (sliderIndex + 1) % slider.length;
  result.appendChild(slider[sliderIndex]);
}

forwardButton.addEventListener('click', forward);
```

```html
<button id="forwardButton">Increment</button>
<div id="carrouselcontainer"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Incrementing an array will not work but only generate error.

`forward()` should remove the actual child of the carrousel and 
add a new child that has as value the next element of the `slider` array:

Introduce a `currentSlide` number variable to indicate the current index displayed and increment it in `forward()`.

```
var currentSlide = 0;
...
carrousel.appendChild(slider[currentSlide]);
...

function forward() {

  carrousel.removeChild(slider[currentSlide++]);
  if (currentSlide >= slider.length){
     currentSlide = 0; 
  }
  carrousel.appendChild(slider[currentSlide]);
}
```

Comment: @GhostCat I hope so for both :)  As I would see you again, I would talk maybe to a legend :) see you :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace the element only incrementing the element does not work:

I added a counter "silderPos" to your script, so you can increment it by one on every click.

If it larger then 2 it will go back to 0 by a modulo action.

I made the carrouselElement global, so that your click script can access the element directly.

With this changes i can now go throu all of your element.

Please find the modified source code here:

```
var carrouselElement;
var sliderPos = 0;
function carrousel()
{
    carrouselElement = document.getElementById('carrouselcontainer');

    var slide1 = document.createElement('div');
    slide1.className = 'slide1';

    var slide2 = document.createElement('div');
    slide2.className = 'slide2';

    var slide3 = document.createElement('div');
    slide3.className = 'slide3';

    var slider = [slide1, slide2, slide3]

carrouselElement.appendChild(slider[0]);

    var backButton = document.getElementById('backButton');
    var forwardButton = document.getElementById('forwardButton')

function forward() {
        carrouselElement.lastChild.remove();
        sliderPos++;
        sliderPos = sliderPos % 3;
        carrouselElement.appendChild(slider[sliderPos]);
    }

    /*backButton.addEventListener('click', back)*/
    forwardButton.addEventListener('click', forward)

}

window.addEventListener('load', carrousel);
```